# multiple conditions on same column, clob

Tags: sql, oracle

how do I select rows based on multiple values in the same column.
I want to select all row IDs that have both Apple and Orange
e.g.

T1

```
ID    Value
1     Apple
1     Orange
2     Apple
2     Kiwi
3     Pear
3     Berry
3     Orange
4     Apple
5     Apple
5     Orange
5     Kiwi
```

so here is my output:

```
1  
5
```

how do I do an AND on the column 'Value'. Also, the column 'Value' is a clob type.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but is a bit wasteful since it scans the full table twice. The "intersect" part is not too bad, because it is on result sets of id's only.

```
select id from t1 where dbms_lob.compare(value, to_clob('Apple'))  = 0
intersect
select id from t1 where dbms_lob.compare(value, to_clob('Orange')) = 0;
```

If you need faster performance (if you have a lot of rows and the clobs are large), perhaps this will work faster (scanning the full table just once):

```
with x (id, a, o) as (
        select id, case dbms_lob.compare(value, to_clob('Apple'))  when 0 then 1 end,
                   case dbms_lob.compare(value, to_clob('Orange')) when 0 then 1 end
        from t1
     )
select   id 
from     x
group by id
having   count(a) > 0 and count(o) > 0;
```

This is still somewhat wasteful, because the second `dbms_lob.compare()` is performed even if the first one is successful. If you need even faster performance, the query can be re-written to avoid this duplication.

As usual, the more performance you need, the more complicated the query gets. You need to decide on the proper balance between the two.

Comment: here is how I think I was able to achieve it:                                       select id from t1
where ((dbms_lob.instr(upper(value),upper('apple'),1,1)>0)
or (dbms_lob.instr(upper(value),upper('apple'),1,1)>0)
)
group by t1.id having count(*)>1

Comment: I understand the use of `upper(value)` - you are concerned it may not be written exactly like this: `Apple`. I don't understand `upper('Apple')` - why not just simply `'APPLE'`? Also, are you looking for values that may CONTAIN apple, or that ARE EQUAL TO apple? Your query will pick up Grapefruit if you are searching for Grape. If you want EQUAL, then use the `compare` function, as I show in my Answer. Finally, your solution checking for count(*) > 1 will work - but it will NOT work if your table may have duplicate pairs (id, Value). If that is not possible you should be OK.